# PHP IP Filtering

Tags: php, ip, filtering

i want to allow users to filter their login based on their ip address (a new settings in the user preferences i will implement).

so if a user with a specific ip login and there is not restriction, the login is successful.

in any other case i was thinking this

if the user choose his full IP like 67.31.85.47 and he has this IP then the login is good
if a user choose 67.31.85.* and has this IP then the login is good
if a user choose 67.31.*.* and has this IP then the login is good
if a user choose 67.*.*.* and has this IP then the login is good
any other case it's invalid

the user can choose up to 5 IP restrictions. eg:

```
67.31.*.*
167.77.47.*
62.11.28.28
25.57.*.*
169.*.*.*
```

i was tinking to strip the IP using explode and then compared to all restrictions he setup. 
this can be slow since i have to check 5 times * 4 (4 = IP exploded on the dot)

is there a faster way to do it?
thanks

Comment: Consider converting those IPs to normal integers and using netmasks. Then it's a simple bit-wise AND operation for each IP address to be checked. `if ((userIP && netmask) == (filterIP && netmask)) { ok to go }`.

Comment: Since you seem to be filtering on the old-school /8 boundaries, you'd need 3 netmasks. 0xFF000000, 0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFFFF00. apply the relevant mask to each ip in your table, apply it to the user's IP, and if the masked values are equal, they're in the same IP block.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<?php
function testIP($ip) {
    if($ip == '*' || $ip == '*.*.*.*') {
        return TRUE;
    }
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    $mask = str_replace('.*', '', $ip);
    return strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $mask) === 0;
}

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '70.69.68.67';

$ip = '1.11.1.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '2.34.9.1';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '70.11.*.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '70.69.68.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '70.69.*.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '70.*.*.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '*.*.*.*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
$ip = '*';
echo "Is $ip good: "; var_dump(testIP($ip));
```

will output:

```
Is 1.11.1.* good: bool(false)
Is 2.34.9.1 good: bool(false)
Is 70.11.*.* good: bool(false)
Is 70.69.68.* good: bool(true)
Is 70.69.*.* good: bool(true)
Is 70.*.*.* good: bool(true)
Is *.*.*.* good: bool(true)
Is * good: bool(true)
```

If you are looking for specific ip (no wild card) checking, you can use:

```
function is_private_ip($ip) {
  return filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) != FALSE;
}
```

var_dump(is_private_ip('82.237.3.3'));
var_dump(is_private_ip('748.1234.5.4'));

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this idea help for you:

```
<?php
$ip_restrict = "67.31.*.*
167.77.47.*
62.11.28.28
25.57.*.*
169.*.*.*";

$ip_restrict = array_flip(explode("\n", $ip_restrict));
$ip = preg_match("!([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)!", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip_match);


$ip_in_blacklist = false;
$ip_check_1 = $ip_match[1] . '.*.*.*';
$ip_check_2 = $ip_match[1] . '.' . $ip_match[2] . '.*.*';
$ip_check_3 = $ip_match[1] . '.' . $ip_match[2] . '.' . $ip_match[3] . '.*';
$ip_check_4 = $ip_match[1] . '.' . $ip_match[2] . '.' . $ip_match[3] . '.' . $ip_match[4];

if (isset($ip_restrict[$ip_check_1]) || isset($ip_restrict[$ip_check_2]) || isset($ip_restrict[$ip_check_3]) || isset($ip_restrict[$ip_check_4])) {
    $ip_in_blacklist = true;
}

var_dump($ip_in_blacklist);
```

;

Comment: why using a preg_match? why not explode? what's the difference?

Comment: It's easy to format and validate :) you may use explode, i do not see any difference

Comment: explode does not use regexp vs preg_match is

Answer (score 0):

```
$auth_ip=array();
$client_ip=array();
$client_ip=explode(".", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$auth_ip=explode("\n", $patner_name_id[0]['client_ip']);
$j=0;
$flag=0;

foreach ($auth_ip as $value) {
    $i=0;
    $value=explode(".", $value);
    foreach ($value as $valueip) {
        if($valueip!="*") { 
            if($valueip!=$client_ip[$i]){
                $flag=1;
                 break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            $i++;
            continue;
        }               
    }
}

if($flag==1){
    header("Location:".$default_company);           
    exit;
}
```